# How to create threads in a loop, in an anonymous class referring to the loop variable?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, server

I'm doing a concurrent server program and I'm testing it.
Into a JUnit Test I'm typing this:

```
[...]

Client[] clients = new Client[30];
for ( int i = 0; i<30 ; i++){
    clients[i] = new Client("localhost", SERVPORT);
}

for ( Integer i = 0; i<30 ; i++){
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            clients[i].send(i.toString()); <--
        }
    }.start();
}
[...]
```

The problem is that Java doesn't compile because I cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different method, so I have to modify and write i as final (but I shouldn't). I understand that, but... How can I send messages from all the clients concurrently?

Additional information:
In the method `send(String)`, I send a message to the server and wait until the server responds.

Comment: Why `i` is Integer not `int` is there any reason?

Comment: Because I want send to the server i.toString() and for that method I need an object which is Integer and isn't int

Comment: You know that you can use `Integer.toString(n)`, the static method, where `n` is `int`, without actually creating an `Integer` object?

Comment: Thank you so much I didn't remember that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the thread from within the original `for` loop, skipping the use of the index variable `i` by referencing a local variable instead:

```
final Client[] clients = new Client[30];
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    final Integer integer = new Integer(i);
    final Client client = new Client("localhost", SERVPORT);
    clients[i] = client;
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            client.send(integer.toString());
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Note the `final` Integer created for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < clients.length; i++){
  new Thread(()->{
     clients[i].send(i+"");
  }).start();
}
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner is more likely to learn something!

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own thread class that accepts a Client parameter in the constructor.

```
class MyThread extends Thread
{
    private Client client;
    private String message;
    MyThread(Client client, String message)
    {
        this->client = client;
        this->message = message;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        client.send(message);
    }
}
```